# list of all HTML attributes which accept Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know ALL the attributes of HTML elements which can accept JavaScript, like `onLoad`, `onBlur` events, `submit` attribute of forms, etc. 
Is there any such comprehensive list? 
I would also like to know if there is any easy way to select all of the attributes using jQuery. 
Thanks!

Comment: “All” in which sense? As defined in some specification? Then look at that specification. As implemented in browsers? That would be a large list and would change as browsers change. And “accept Javascript” in which sense? What about e.g. `href="javascript:alert('foo')"`? And what would you do with the information?

Comment: I want to analyse all the javascript in a web page. So I would like to collect all executable sources in a webpage. Yeah I also would like to handle the case of `javascript:alert("foo")` Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through the following link,you will get your answer

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: @everconfusedGuy if i answered your question than u can mark my answer as answered.thanks.

Comment: haha I tried to..apparently I can accept your answer only after 10 minutes, dont know why. Will do it then

Comment: w3schools should not be used as a reference of any kind, or at all, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yup but I at least wanted to start off somewhere. Is there any better way of finding out all possible JavaScript in a HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

**Window Event Attributes**

```
onafterprintNew 
onbeforeprintNew    
onbeforeunloadNew   
onerrorNew  
onload  script  
onmessageNew    
onofflineNew    
ononlineNew     
onpagehideNew   
onpageshowNew   
onpopstateNew   
onredoNew   
onresizeNew     
onstorageNew    
onundoNew   
onunload
```

**Form Events**

```
onblur  
onchange    
oncontextmenuNew    
onfocus     
onformchangeNew     
onforminputNew  
oninputNew  
oninvalidNew    
onselect    
onsubmit
```

**For Full Refrence**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: I would also like to know other attributes like submit attribute of the form tag, etc